# Error in system command traceroute c

Tags: c, sockets, telnet

I'm trying to develop a traceroute server which accepts argument from a telnet client performs traceroute and send the information back to the telnet client. I'm receiving the argument from telnet client at the server for e.g. `traceroute www.google.com` but somehow when I try to execute it, it gives me a weird error:

```
: Name or service not known
' on position 1 (argc 1)line arg `www.google.com
```

What I found strange is when I hard code the command at the server end it works fine, also when I receive the command at the server end and print it out, that works fine too. However, the same command received in a character array it fails to execute with the above error.

Here's my code:

```
int main() {
int sockfd,new_fd;
char client_arg[100];

//Create a socket and establish the connection

if (recv(new_fd,client_arg,100,0)== -1)
            perror("recv");

printf("%s\n",client_arg); // prints traceroute www.google.com
system(client_arg);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many things could be wrong here:

- `traceroute` might not be in the default `PATH` of `/bin/sh`,
- the string might not be zero-terminated,
- the buffer might have some unprintable characters that `printf` would not show to you,
- you might receive a short read with partial command,
- anything else ...

It is a very Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup> to blindly pass user (or network) input for execution like that. Do explicit checking. Pass only allowed commands. Check correctness of the arguments.

Comment: Thank you that was useful. The first two points you mentioned aren't an issue in this case. Because even though I didn't mention it in the code, I have zero terminated the string. And I checked hard coding the command it works! So i believe traceroute path is a default path of /bin/sh.

Comment: However, I think the third point is most likely what is wrong. Looking at the error I think there's that extra single quote before the hostname. But I tried getting only the hostname from user and implemented traceroute independently like this: `int ret = sprintf(buffer, "traceroute %s",client_arg);` and then `system(buffer);` even that gives the same error!